# How to see all computers connected to a network

Tags: networking, lan

I am in a LAN and there are 3 Ubuntu, 2 Kubuntu, 2 Windows XP and 2 Windows 7. What commands or tools are available to see what PCs are connected to the LAN that it shows the name of the PC and the IP. Similar to tools like Angry IP that show all PCs in a LAN.

Note that I do not know the IPs or names of the computers connected to the LAN. So the tool or command should look for them to.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/261818/how-can-i-list-all-ips-in-the-connected-network-through-terminal-preferably

Comment: None of the answers actually answers the question for me on Ubuntu 18.04 and a school LAN.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Taken from [Finding All Hosts On the LAN From Linux/Windows Workstation](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mapping-lan-with-linux-unix-ping-command/)

```bsh
for ip in $(seq 1 254); do ping -c 1 192.168.1.$ip>/dev/null; 
    [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "192.168.1.$ip UP" || : ;
done
```

But for a great tool, [Nmap](http://nmap.org). Great for mapping networks.

Comment: this would work only when the subnet is using /24 addressing.

Comment: +1 That's a pretty spiffy little IP address scanner.

Comment: Your local IP may be very different than this...

Comment: This only shows my default gateway IP

Answer (score 65):

Arp-scan works great for me too...

If using Wi-Fi:

```
sudo arp-scan -l --interface=wlan0
```

-or if using ethernet:

```
sudo arp-scan -l --interface=eth0
```

(this last is practically identical to what Rajesh Rajendran posted; the -l standing for --localnet)

If you don't have arp-scan (it doesn't come with Ubuntu by default), just pull up a terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install arp-scan
```

Comment: If this doesn't work use ifconfig to get a list of interfaces and try switching eth0 to something else.

Comment: It's not showing any IPs for me. ```sudo arp-scan -l --interface=wlp4s0
Interface: wlp4s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.9.5 with 256 hosts 

14 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.9.5: 256 hosts scanned in 1.975 seconds (129.62 hosts/sec). 0 responded```

Comment: how do I find the correct wifi interface?  Mine is not `wlan0`

Comment: arp-scan don't exist in Ubuntu 20.xx so this article are out of date and are only confusing people.

Comment: You can also `sudo lshw -c network` to see all your network interfaces

Comment: @mLstudent33 It should be something like `wlp2s0` Run `iwconfig` and it should be the last on the list.

Answer (score 49):

The simplest thing is

```
$ sudo arp-scan --localnet
```

Comment: `arp-scan -l` does the same thing.

Comment: I want a list of all the hosts.  This doesn't do that.

Comment: I get `ERROR: Could not obtain MAC address for interface tun0`

Answer (score 37):

I always use [nmap](https://nmap.org). To scan for all devices in your network, use:

`nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24`

More here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/

It is a great tool to know about. You may want to install `nmap` using:

`sudo apt-get install nmap` if you are using Debian or

`sudo pacman -S nmap` if you are using Arch.

Comment: What do to For Fedora?

Comment: @supershnee Do a `yum install nmap`

Comment: And now for Fedora 25 and + : `dnf install nmap` will install nmap

Answer (score 17):

As a possible GUI option, the best one I have seen is Angry IP as found in http://angryip.org/download/#linux

Simply download the latest DEB package and install. Then run ipscan from Dash. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: does it filter only linux machines, if yes please guide me how.

Comment: it is really  good, I added all fetchers to the list columns, what helped most were hostname and macvendor, now everything connected to my wifi is more understandable, thx!

Comment: is wire shark better for tasks like this?  how about kali linux?

Comment: @AquariusPower Where does one find the `macvendor` feature?

Comment: @JeffWard menu: tools/fetchers//availableFetchers//"lastItemOnTheList", then sort by macvendor, it is a short name of the hardware like D-Link

Answer (score 10):

### arp

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
iPhone-von-me.fritz.box  ether   12:55:05:30:3c:df   C                     wlp3s0
android-abcdefghijklmno  ether   11:66:3f:71:04:d6   C                     wlp3s0
fritz.box                ether   00:11:3f:46:37:c2   C                     wlp3s0
Blupiblu.fritz.box       ether   71:88:cc:bb:dc:a6   C                     wlp3s0
```

### ip neigh

`ip neigh` and `hosts`. **NO nmap / sudo required**.

Building on this, you can build a Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""List all hosts with their IP adress of the current network."""

import os

out = os.popen('ip neigh').read().splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(out, start=1):
    ip = line.split(' ')[0]
    h = os.popen('host {}'.format(ip)).read()
    hostname = h.split(' ')[-1]
    print("{:>3}: {} ({})".format(i, hostname.strip(), ip))
```

Download via

```
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MartinThoma/699ae445b8a08b5afd16f7d6f5e5d0f8/raw/577fc32b57a7f9e66fdc9be60e7e498bbec7951a/neighbors.py
```

Comment: the only output was: `1: _gateway. (207.23.10.xx4)` where xx are digits

Answer (score 7):

**If broadcast isn't disabled on your router...**

You can ping the broadcast address.

```
ping -b 192.168.0
```

Will broadcast the ping command to every host within the 192.168.0/24 subnet.

*Note: It's probably a good idea to keep broadcasting turned off though as that's how hackers can exploit a network using a DDOS Smurf attack. Basically, ping the broadcast address with a packet that has a spoofed destination address (ie the ip address of the victim). There's a little more to it than that but that's what Google is for.*

*Note: The same also works on Windows but you ping the actual broadcast address (not the subnet).*

```
ping -b 192.168.0.255
```

Answer (score 3):

Nmap is your friend

nmap -sP 192.168.0.1/24

If you have any question, `nmap help` is full of information.

Answer (score 0):

1. Script to send email in Shell and Powershell where it is asked to user credentials  when you run the script.
2. Script to check online devices in the network for both Linux and Windows Clients.
3. Script to check disk space of devices detected by previous script for both Windows and Linux.