# Linux alternative for advanced ip scanner

Tags: networking, software-recommendation

A friend of my lately introduced to tools called [advanced IP scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/). It a great tool. It basically scans all addresses to check the address of device even if this device is not in our network. When I connect a device on my computer and I don't know its IP address. If the device has 1.1.1.1 or 3.3.3 or 6.6.6.6 8.8.8.8 this tool will find it. A tool like Nmap works to find it if I know the range where my device could be.

I was wondering if there is a Linux alternative for this tool.

Comment: Or https://askubuntu.com/q/82480/158442 .. essentially, nmap.

Comment: The arp tools can be helpful for cases where you don't know the IP range, for example, `sudo arp -n`.